# Independence criteria for $3$ events versus independence criteria of $3$ RVs with a joint pdf/pmf

Tags: probability

Learning first year probability, could use your help.

**Background**

- The RVs $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with joint pdf $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$ are independent if you can factor $f$ into $$f(x,y,z) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)f_Z(z)$$
- The events $E$, $F$ and $G$ are independent if:
  $$P(EFG) = P(E)P(F)P(G)$$
  $$P(EF) = P(E)P(F)$$
  $$P(EG) = P(E)P(G)$$
  $$P(FG) = P(F)P(G)$$

**My question**

To my beginner mind, there is an "asymmetry" when talking about the independence criteria of $3$ RVs versus $3$ events. Don't get me wrong, I am very happy that the independence criteria for $3$ RVs with a joint pdf does not include testing $f_{X,Y} = f_Xf_Y$ and the other two cases.

*Can you explain why the independence criteria seems "asymmetrical" to a beginner (me)?*

Is it something about having a joint pdf that eliminates the need for testing the $\binom{3}{2}$ other cases. Or is it the fact that there is more flexibility in creating wacky events and more rules around RVs?

Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Remember that to obtain the distribution $f_{X,Y}$, for example, you can simply sum/integrate over $Z$: $$f_{X,Y} = \begin{cases}f_X(x)f_Y(y)\int_\Omega f_Z(z)\;dz & \text{ for }Z\text{ continuous}\\ f_X(x)f_Y(y)\sum_z f_Z(z) & \text{ for }Z\text{ discrete}\end{cases}$$ So, if $f(x,y,z) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)f_Z(z)$, then $f_{X,Y} = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$

Comment: Ahh I see... that makes sense... thanks!!

Comment: @bames okay I think I am close to understanding now. The reason you don't have to check the $\binom{3}{2}$ cases for the $3$ RVs is because of your comment. The reason why you do have to check the $\binom{3}{2}$ cases for events is because $P(E)$ is a constant number whereas $P(X)$ is going to vary from zero to one via it's distribution. So knowing $P(EFG) = P(E)P(F)P(G)$ is not as powerful as knowing $f = f_Xf_Yf_Z$ which you can do more with.